# Почему не обрабатывается нажатие на кнопку в js?

Tags: javascript, html

Вот простенький код с кнопкой в html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="./js/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <center><button id='button'>ОКЕЙ</button></center>

</body>
</html>
```

А вот мой код в js:

```
(function (window, document) {
    function init() { 
        var button = document.getElementById("button") ;
        button.onclick = handleButtonClick; 
} 
    function handleButtonClick() { 
        alert("Вы нажали на кнопку"); 
            
}
})(window, document);
```

При нажатие на кнопку ОКЕЙ должно выводиться уведомление "Вы нажали на кнопку", но ничего не происходит. Помогите исправить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="./js/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Указываем функцию которая будет вызвана после нажатия на кнопку onclick="handleButtonClick()" -->
    <center>
    <button id='button' onclick="handleButtonClick()">ОКЕЙ</button>
    <button id='button_1'>ОКЕЙ 1</button>
    <!-- Указываем вывод сообщения после нажатия на кнопку onclick="alert('сообщение')" -->
    <button id='button' onclick="alert('Вы нажали на кнопку ОКЕЙ 2')">ОКЕЙ 2</button>
    <button id='button' onclick="redirect()">Редирект в гугл</button>
    
    </center>

</body>
</html>

<script>
  function handleButtonClick() { 
        alert("Вы нажали на кнопку ОКЕЙ");  
        }
        
        function redirect() { 
        location="https://www.google.com/;"  
        }
        
        //или если нужно отследить нажатие без указания onclick на кнопке
        button_1.onclick = function() {
    alert('Вы нажали на кнопку ОКЕЙ 1');
  };
</script>
```

Comment: Это помогло, а можно как нибудь так же сделать редирект на другой html документ который лежит в этой же папке с основным html документом?

Comment: Желательно что бы это было в отдельном файле

Comment: Больше о редиректе можно прочесть здесь: http://redirekt.info/article/pishem-redirekt-na-javascript-js.html